# How can I find a Checksum of a Docker Image

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker 1.10.3.

[Docker Image Specification v1.0.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.md) says there is an Image Checksum field in a Docker Image JSON Description, like:

```
"checksum": "tarsum.v1+sha256:e58fcf7418d2390dec8e8fb69d88c06ec07039d651fedc3aa72af9972e7d046b",
```

However, there is no such a field in the result of `docker inspect <IMAGE>`.

How can I get the checksum of a particular image?

Comment: Maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046334/what%C2%B4s-the-sha256-code-of-a-docker-image

Comment: as @jDo mentioned, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511811 which answers this: `docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $IMAGE` where $IMAGE can contain the tag.

Answer (score 21):

You have the command

`$ docker images --digests`

for example:

```
docker images --digests busybox
REPOSITORY          TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
busybox             latest              sha256:32f093055929dbc23dec4d03e09dfe971f5973a9ca5cf059cbfb644c206aa83f   00f017a8c2a6        2 months ago        1.11 MB
```

Comment: do you know how can i find sha1 checksum?

Answer (score 5):

```
docker images --digests --format '{{.Digest}}' IMAGE
```

Recent Docker versions introduced this new command that may deprecate the above:

```
docker image ls --digests --format '{{.Digest}}' IMAGE
```