# What does it mean sha256 in Docker, where are directories of layers of image?

Tags: docker

I am newbie at Docker. I have to theoretically question about Docker.  We know that defaultly Docker uses AUFS, layers filesystem.  Where can I find in `/var/libs/docker` folders for each layer ?   I would like to see it.

And second thing:
What is `sha256` ? I know that it is some number-hash. But what does it mean in docker ?

Comment: partial dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046334/what%C2%B4s-the-sha256-code-of-a-docker-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see more at "[Docker and AUFS in practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/)"

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/images/aufs_layers.jpg]

> This diagram shows that each image layer, and the container layer, is represented in the Docker hosts filesystem as a directory under /var/lib/docker/.
>   The union mount point provides the unified view of all layers.
>
> As of Docker 1.10, image layer IDs do not correspond to the names of the directories that contain their data.

As [I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32046927/6309):

> the V2 API does not deal in Image IDs. Rather, it uses digests to identify layers, which can be calculated as property of the layer and are independently verifiable.

See "[Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)":

> This API design is driven heavily by content **addressability**.
>   The core of this design is the concept of a content addressable identifier.
>
> It uniquely identifies content by taking a collision-resistant hash of the bytes. Such an identifier can be independently calculated and verified by selection of a common algorithm.
>   If such an identifier can be communicated in a secure manner, one can retrieve the content from an insecure source, calculate it independently and be certain that the correct content was obtained.
>   Put simply, the identifier is a property of the content.
>
> To disambiguate from other concepts, we call this identifier a **digest**.
>   A digest is a serialized hash result, consisting of a algorithm and hex portion. The algorithm identifies the methodology used to calculate the digest. The hex portion is the hex-encoded result of the hash.
>
> We define a digest string to match the following grammar:

```
 digest := algorithm ":" hex algorithm := /[A-Fa-f0-9_+.-]+/ hex := /[A-Fa-f0-9]+/
```

> Some examples of digests include the following:

```
digest  description
sha256:6c3c624b58dbbcd3c0dd82b4c53f04194d1247c6eebdaab7c610cf7d66709b3b     Common sha256 based digest
```

> While the algorithm does allow one to implement a wide variety of algorithms, compliant implementations should use sha256

Comment: Can I see somewhere difference file (representation of layer) ?

Comment: @JavaNewbie you mean a diff between two layers with the list of files changed?

Comment: @JavaNewbie that would be `docker diff <sha256>`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/diff/#extended-description

Comment: Yes, it is. I would like to find this file. From what I did read each layer = new directory.

Comment: So sha is something like hash of commit in git

Comment: @JavaNewbie yes: a way to uniquely reference a layer. (Even though Git only uses SHA1, not SHA2, which is a bit awkward these days: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42450327/6309)

Comment: Can you try understand last thing ?  Union mount point. I don't understand it. Everywhere it is written: It provides one view on file system, but it is not clear for me

Comment: @JavaNewbie See http://collabnix.com/archives/516: "A union mount is a mount that allows several filesystems to be mounted at one time but appear to be one filesystem."

Comment: Where it is exploited? After all, Each container **has exactly** one AUFS filesystem.

Comment: @JavaNewbie it is exploited when creating an image (committing a container): the result AUFS layer is a Union mount point which is the result of the concatenation of all the previous layers.

Comment: Each layer is mount point? What does it mean mount layer on some point ?

Comment: @JavaNewbie It means that when you use it (as an image or a container), the filesystem you see is the result of the concatenation of all the previous layers.

Comment: The problem is that under: `/var/lib/docker` there is no `aufs` directory, there are for example:  image, network, volumens, containers and so on

Comment: @JavaNewbie what docker version are you using on which host OS?

Comment: v = 1.12,  fedora 25

Comment: (I have some containers)

Comment: @JavaNewbie Then your storage driver might not be AUFS by default: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. So only before AUFS was defautl ?

Comment: Yes, Fedora is Redhat based. from docs: It used devicemapper - and in my case it is true

Comment: could you point me out to an algorithm used to serialize folders, as docker layers are actually folders, not "bytes"?

Comment: @wick Not an exact match to your case, but https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh loads said layers.

Comment: @wick Also https://github.com/p8952/bocker/blob/000633061c6cfcb99c8d9eef5aa483a44318f3e6/bocker#L23-L36