# How to determine the specific version of a Docker image built from a latest/stable tag?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Docker image that was created roughly a year ago. The Dockerfile contains:

`FROM docker:stable`

How can I determine the actual version of the docker image that `stable` was referring to back when the image was built?

Edit: What I want to do, in a nutshell, is replace `FROM docker:stable` with `FROM docker:X.Y.Z` where X.Y.Z is the version tag that "stable" was pointing to a year ago when the image was originally built.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511811/2194007)

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $IMAGE
```

This will give you the sha256 hash of the image.

Then you can use a service like [MicroBadger](https://microbadger.com) to get more info about that specific build.

---

If you want to recreate the Dockerfile you can use [`docker history`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/#description) to examine the layer history:

```
$ docker history docker

IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
3e23a5875458        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8            0 B
8578938dd170        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c dpkg-reconfigure locales &&    loc   1.245 MB
be51b77efb42        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    338.3 MB
4b137612be55        6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD jessie.tar.xz in /        121 MB
750d58736b4b        6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER Tianon Gravi <ad   0 B
511136ea3c5a        9 months ago                                                        0 B
```

Keep in mind that if the image has been manually tampered with, I don't know how reliable this output would be.

---

Finally if you want to go full hacker mode, this old thread on the [Docker community forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-view-the-dockerfile-in-an-image/5687) has some info.

I'm not sure how you can get the tag, because I don't believe this is stored in the image itself, but in the repository. So you'd have to query the repository itself, or get a full list of image history and go detective on it.

Comment: That "docker inspect" command is returning the SHA of the image itself, not the base image. If I do `SHA=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $IMAGE) ; docker pull $(SHA)` I end up with `Status: Image is up to date for $IMAGE`. The SHA that I get doesn't appear to correspond to the "docker:stable" image in any way.

Comment: @BruceP Added a section on docker history. Hope this helps.