# Get SHA's of multiarch docker image

Tags: docker, multiarch

How to get sha's of all the tags corresponding to an image on docker hub. For instance, consider an image with `latest`, `latest-windows` and `latest-linux` tags. On `docker pull image_name:latest`, docker will automagically pull the correct image based on the OS from which the command is being run.

How can I get the SHA's for all the three tags. I found that we can do it using [manifest-tool](https://github.com/estesp/manifest-tool). Is there a way we can do this by using only *docker*.

EDIT:

`docker inspect image_name:tag` will return the sha of only one of the tags either windows or linux depending on the operating system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the sha256 code of a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046334/where-can-i-find-the-sha256-code-of-a-docker-image)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Added an edit explaining.

Comment: latest-windows and latest-linux aren't official tags. You can run the command 3 times and check the difference using bash. Also, it seems odd to use latest-windows and latest-linux tags as docker is build to run on multiple os using the same image. Maybe you should reconsider your idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unbelievable how hard it is to find the multiarch SHA for a given tag.

Since I spend 15-20 minutes every time trying to remember how myself, I'm documenting it here for others.

This is not the official way to do it (what *is* the official way?), but this has reliably worked for me (using a `ruby` image as my example):

```
docker run mplatform/manifest-tool inspect ruby:3.1.2-alpine3.15
```